# Extract subset of data

Tags: r

Ok, I have a matrix of values with certain identifiers, such as:

```
A  2
B  3
C  4
D  5
E  6
F  7
G  8
```

I would like to pull out a subset of these values (using R) based on a list of the identifiers ("B", "D", "E") for example, so I would get the following output:

```
B  3
D  5
E  6
```

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this (some sort of apply?) but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Are the identifiers in their own column?  Or are they the row names of the matrix?

Comment: @RichardScriven, they are the row names of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If the letters are the row names, then you can just use this:

```
m <- matrix(2:8, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:7], NULL))
m[c("B","D","E"),]
# B D E 
# 3 5 6
```

Note that there is a subtle but very important difference between: `m[c("B","D","E"),]` and `m[rownames(m) %in% c("B","D","E"),]`. Both return the same rows, but ***not necessarily in the same order***.

The former uses the character vector `c("B","D","E")` as in index into `m`. As a result, the rows will be returned *in the order of character vector*. For instance:

```
# result depends on order in c(...)
m[c("B","D","E"),]
# B D E 
# 3 5 6 
m[c("E","D","B"),]
# E D B 
# 6 5 3
```

The second method, using `%in%`, creates a logical vector with length = nrow(m). For each element, that element is `T` if the row name is present in `c("B","D","E")`, and `F` otherwise. Indexing with a  logical vector returns rows in the original order:

```
# result does NOT depend on order in c(...)
m[rownames(m) %in% c("B","D","E"),]
# B D E 
# 3 5 6 
m[rownames(m) %in% c("E","D","B"),]
# B D E 
# 3 5 6
```

This is probably more than you wanted to know...

Comment: Oh yeah...I guess that's better.  Haha

Comment: @RichardScriven Not necessarily. As you pointed out, with a matrix having 1 column, this will return a named vector.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix:

```
> m <- matrix(2:8, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:7]))
```

You can use `%in%` to filter out the desired rows. If the original matrix only has a single column,  using `drop = FALSE` will keep the matrix structure. Otherwise it will be converted to a named vector.

```
> m[rownames(m) %in% c("B", "D", "E"), , drop = FALSE]
#   [,1]
# B    3
# D    5
# E    6
```